# Find a value in common in two two-dimensionals arrays Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have two arrays, and each is two dimensional, I want to take the value of array 1 in position i and try to find the same value in array 2. If they have the same value, the values of array 2 in x position is concatenated in array 1 in position i.

example

Array 1

[[***1***,2,3,4,5,6],[3,5,7,2,12,5],[a,f,3,d,4,g]]

Array 2

[[b,e,w,1,4,6] , [***1***,0,8,5,8,9]]

So the new array 1 will be

[[***1***,2,3,4,5,6,***1***,0,8,5,8,9],[3,5,7,2,12,5],[a,f,3,d,4,g]]

Any thought.....

Comment: It's customary to give it a go and put in your code that shows you've spent five minutes trying to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm doing an iteration of the array 2 inside array 1 to check if the value is the same

Comment: Please show your attempt at a solution, and explain where you're stuck.

Comment: If `a`, `g`, etc. are strings (rather than variables or methods), please surround them with single or double quotes.  What would be the desired result if the second element of Array 2 were `[0,1,8]`? What if the first element of both arrays in Array 2 were `1`? What if more than one array in Array 1 contained a `1`? Please answer by editing.

Answer (score 0):

Your description of the task isn't correct. You can't

> take the value of the array 1 in position i

because `array 1` contain arrays itself, so you can take value in position `i, j`. And search for same values in `array 2` in each `i` on position `j`. And if this is what you want, here is sample code:

```ruby
arr_1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [3, 5, 7, 2, 12, 5], ['a', 'f', 3, 'd', 4, 'g']]
arr_2 = [['b', 'e', 'w', 1, 4, 6], [1, 0, 8, 5, 8, 9]]

search_i = 0
search_j = 0

search_val = arr_1[search_i][search_j]

arr_2.each_with_index do |val_i, i|
  val_i.each_with_index do |val_j, j|
    if j == search_j && arr_2[i][j] == search_val
      arr_1[search_i].concat(arr_2[i])
    end
  end
end

p arr_1 # [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 0, 8, 5, 8, 9], [3, 5, 7, 2, 12, 5], ["a", "f", 3, "d", 4, "g"]]
```